# Drop-down in ionic select

Tags: ionic-framework

I am developing a application in ionic in which I should display inputboxes like pnr no ,train no,when train is elected from drop-down and when I select bus from drop-down it should input boxes related to bus like seat no etc

Comment: Thanks for sharing that with us. Did you have a **question**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code, this will work.

**in your .html page:**

```
<ion-label floating>Travel By</ion-label>
<ion-select (ionCancel)="cancel()">
    <ion-option value="Bus" (ionSelect)="selectTravel('Bus');">Bus</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Train" (ionSelect)="selectTravel('Train');">Train</ion-option>
</ion-select>

<ion-label floating *ngIf="isTrainSelected">Train No</ion-label>
<ion-input *ngIf="isTrainSelected"></ion-input>

<ion-label floating *ngIf="isBusSelected">Seat No</ion-label>
<ion-input *ngIf="isBusSelected"></ion-input>
```

**in your .ts page:**

```
public isTrainSelected: boolean;
public isBusSelected: boolean;

selectTravel(Mode)
{
    if(Mode == 'Bus')
    {
        this.isTrainSelected = false;
        this.isBusSelected = true;
    }
    else if(Mode == 'Train')
    {
        this.isBusSelected = false;
        this.isTrainSelected = true;
    }
}

cancel()
{
    this.isBusSelected = false;
    this.isTrainSelected = false;
}

ionViewDidLoad() 
{
    //make it invisible on page load
    this.isBusSelected = false;
    this.isTrainSelected = false;
}
```

Mark this answer as accepted and upvote if it works. :)